# Change animation duration with slider by binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, 3d

I am spinning a 3D house with the following code inside a storyboard:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HouseRotate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="-359" Duration="{Binding StringFormat=0:0:{0}, ElementName=slDuration, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
```

I want the duration property to change based on the slider value, but it seems to be stuck at 1 second. I know the value of the slider is changing properly, because I have outputted it to a label.

Comment: Do you get an output error with this binding as is?

Comment: I don't get any error, but I've never had XAML give me a runtime error so I don't know if it is silently broken

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you need a proper converter in order to convert from `double` (`Slider`'s property Value returns a `double`) to a [Duration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.duration(v=vs.110).aspx) struct.

Take a look to this simple example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DoubleToDurationConverter x:Key="DoubleToDurationConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Click me for an animation" Margin="20" Padding="20">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="Green"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                FillBehavior="Stop" 
                                Duration="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToDurationConverter}}" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>

    <Slider Name="slider" Minimum="10" Maximum="40" Value="30"
            Margin="5" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

Where the convert's code is:

```
public class DoubleToDurationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)value));
        return duration;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Keep in consideration that it is not possible to change the animation's duration while it is running. You can change it just when it is idle.

Comment: Yeah, I saw doing this as a possibility but wanted to see if it could be done using only XAML. I ended up doing it all in C# by stopping the animation, changing the properties I needed to, and restarting.

Comment: IMHO @AnubhavSrivastava it is not possibile to do it just by using XAML: you need some lines of code (as you did)