# Can I use data-binding on the Duration of an Animation in a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I found a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650412/change-animation-duration-with-slider-by-binding) here on SO of how to bind the `Duration` property of a `ColorAnimation` to the `Value` property of a `Slider`. One uses a converter to convert the `Double` value from the slider to a `Duration`, and a `Binding` to have that set the `Duration` of the `ColorAnimation`. Here, abbreviated, is how that works:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DoubleToDurationConverter x:Key="DoubleToDurationConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Slider x:Name="slider" />


<Button Content="Click me for an animation">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="Green"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                        FillBehavior="Stop" 
                        Duration="{Binding ElementName=slider, 
                                           Path=Value,
                                           Mode=OneWay,
                                           Converter={StaticResource DoubleToDurationConverter}}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I tried that and it worked fine for me. But what I want to do is bind the `Duration` to a dependency property called `FadeTime` I've added to my custom control. So, in that control's `ControlTemplate` I have this:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsLit" Value="true">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="glow"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="1"
                                     Duration="{Binding FadeTime, Mode=OneWay,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

This compiles, but gives me an error message at run-time:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree
>   for use across threads.

How can I bind my `DoubleAnimation`'s `Duration` to a dependency variable in a custom control's `ControlTemplate`?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Data-binding is actually gross overkill for what I want to do. Real data-binding would allow for the property's value to change at run-time. All I really want is a way for the developer who is using my custom control to be able to set the `Duration` of the `DoubleAnimation` at design time, without having to edit the `ControlTemplate`. It's okay if the value the developer chooses never changes at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining the animation in your XAML markup, you could define it programmatically in the `PropertyChangedCallback` for the `IsLit` property.

You could simply define another property that lets the consumer of the control specify the duration of the animation.

Here is an example for you.

**Control:**

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    private UIElement glow;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DurationProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Duration", typeof(TimeSpan),
         typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));

    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(DurationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DurationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLitProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("IsLit", typeof(bool),
         typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsLitChanged)));

    public bool IsLit
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsLitProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsLitProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        glow = Template.FindName("glow", this) as UIElement;
        if (glow != null && IsLit)
            Animate(glow);

    }

    private static void OnIsLitChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if(newValue)
        {
            MyCustomControl c = d as MyCustomControl;
            if(c != null && c.glow != null)
            {
                c.Animate(c.glow);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Animate(UIElement glow)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.To = 1;
        animation.Duration = Duration;
        glow.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ct" TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
    <Border x:Name="glow" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red" Opacity="0.1">
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:MyCustomControl Template="{StaticResource ct}" Duration="0:0:5" IsLit="True" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, @mm8! A shame there is (apparently) no pure XAML way to do this, but maybe the mantra of, "XAML, nothing but XAML" ought not to be absolute. Thanks for the great assist!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't use normal bindings inside the storyboard of a control template. Since you just want a way for developers to change the value, one of the following options might work for you:

(1) Use `StaticResource`: Place a duration object somewhere outside the control template, where it's easier to change for developers. However, it needs to be somewhere statically accessible to the control template, since `DynamicResource` won't work in this place.

```
<Duration x:Key="MyCustomDuration">0:0:1</Duration>
... then later
Duration="{StaticResource MyCustomDuration}"
```

(2) Use a static code behind field with `x:Static`:

```
public static class SettingsClass
{
    public static Duration MyCustomDuration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
}
```

and use:

```
Duration="{x:Static local:SettingsClass.MyCustomDuration}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Those both work, but appear to call for the developer to be making changes to my custom control's source code, or else editing a copy of my control's `ControlTemplate`. Nothing inherently wrong with those approaches, but I'm looking for something a little more streamlined.